# Select query in sql not retrieving the value in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

If i have `employee_id` with `integer` (like `1001`) alone, am getting the answer

example the code like this ,

```
   $claimprocess = Employee::find()
                    ->where("employee_id = '1004'  and importcompany_id = 1")
                    ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'")
                    ->all();
```

if i have a `employee_id` with combination `interger` and `character`, am not able get a answer(like `E1004`),

example code like below,

```
$claimprocess = Employee::find()
                    ->where("employee_id = 'E1004'  and importcompany_id = 1")
                    ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'")
                    ->all();
```

When I execute this code, am getting error like below

> Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ
>   'E1004' inconnu dans where clause The SQL being executed
>   was: SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE (employee_id = E1004  and
>   importcompany_id = 1) AND ( status != 'Deleted' )'

UPDATED:

actually am getting that value(E1004) from another variable, I use the variable instead of value, for understanding purpose I have used a value there in my question

Comment: `employee_id = E1004` it need to be `employee_id = 'E1004'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the value correctly , as if now you are not passing the value correctly , hence Yii is not generating Sql query correctly. You can pass second parameter to to where clause

```
    $claimprocess = Employee::find()
                        ->where("employee_id = ':employee_id'  and importcompany_id = 1" , array(':employee_id'=>'E1004'))
                        ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'")
                        ->all();
```

Comment: Actually am passing literal value, i have a variable that contains value like 1003, E1004. i understanding purpose i have used value instead of variable

Comment: i have use like this **$claimprocess = Employee::find()
                    ->where("employee_id = $employee_id and importcompany_id = 1")
                    ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'")
                    ->all();**

Comment: `->where("employee_id = ':employee_id'  and importcompany_id = 1" , array(':employee_id'=>$valueVariable))`

Comment: try like this `$claimprocess = Employee::find() ->where("employee_id = '$employee_id' and importcompany_id = 1") ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'") ->all();`

Comment: great :) , sometime we forget the basics

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose your `employee_id` value i.e. `E1004` within quotes its because  it contains string literals. So your query looks like a

```
->where("employee_id = 'E1004'  and importcompany_id = 1")
```

Comment: actually am getting that value from another variable, i use the variable instead of value, for understanding purpose i have used a value there in my question

Comment: So enclose that variable along with quotes then

Answer (score 1):

String literals in SQL are denoted with single quotes (`'`). Without them, the database would interpret `E1004` as a column name, and fail the query, since your table doesn't have such a query.

```
$claimprocess = Employee::find()
                ->where("employee_id = 'E1004'  and importcompany_id = 1")
                ->andwhere(" status != 'Deleted' and relationship = 'Self'")
                ->all();
```